# powershell - Use a function with unknown number of variables and other parameters

Tags: function, powershell

I need to create a function.
First variable must be an array with an unknown number of parameters plus another variable.
My problem is that I don't know how distinguish between them.

I post an example:

```
function conc-str {
param([string[]]$array,[string]$name)
foreach($item in $array) {
$str+= $item
}
write-host $str
}

conc-str(@("aa","bb","cc"),"dd")
```

The result of this function is

```
aa bb ccdd
```

but as you can see I loop array elements and concatenate them. I thought to get just

```
aa bb cc
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The syntax is a little bit different when compared to most other high level languages. Parameters are not separated by a comma and there are no surrounding braces.

Comment: Thank you stej for your reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you call it is:

```
conc-str @("aa","bb","cc") "dd"
```

You don't use "," as a parameter seperator in PowerShell. It is just a space. The moment you put a "," it becomes a single parameter.